# Regex and mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to write the correct regular expression when the `url` has question marks inside.

*The url*:

```
http://example.com/?s2=1ce05156af2162c654b25a6e0491223269?lang=en
```

The rewrite I have made but not working

```
RewriteRule ^s2=[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\?lang=en\b /subscription-confirmation/?lang=en [L,R=301]
```

Important that it looks for `?s2= and ?lang=en`

I use `mod_rewrite` to do the redirect.

How do I match the `regex` so it actually matches similar to the one above?

Comment: Why would a URL have 2 `?` in it? One of the `?` should be encoded.

Comment: I assume you're actually wanting to inspect the query string? Look at adding a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` statement and test your regex against that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s2=[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\?lang=en 
RewriteRule .*$ /subscription-confirmation/?lang=en [L,R=301]
```